# What succulent is this?

Tags: identification, succulents

I've been searching but all I can find is the Jade plant, which is similar yet no the same.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically found it: "sedum praealtum"

Comment: Please mark your question as answered in a couple days.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a branch of S. praealtum will start cresting.  This creates a very unique look and is suited to a special pot.  (you can break off that stem in early spring and let it root in its new  home - w/o water for a few weeks)